# Regex to match words and acronyms in camel case string

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to capture the word parts of a string that is camel case and might have an acronym in it. In other words, I want to split a camel case string into its words and acronyms.

For example:

```
SomeABCWords
```

... has three capture groups

```
Some ABC Words
```

So far I've found this regex:

```
((?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]+)
```

But that won't handle the acronyms and would just match 'Some' and 'Words'.

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Since your regex matches `Some` and `Words` it should match the whole string. Do you want to _split_ the string into individual words?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])`

Comment: @Chris yes I want to split the string into the words and acronyms

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov that seems to work!! Thanks! Could you add that as an answer? Otherwise I'll add it in a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is to capture abbreviations with added negative lookahead.

```
[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/rV3aT7/1)

Comment: The image illustrates the regex nicely, what did you use to produce it ?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work, at least for the case you posted :

```
[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]*(?![a-z])
```